# Monitoring Storm Topologies, specifically using JMX

Tags: jmx, apache-storm

How to get the visualVm to show information of jvm apache storm runs,
I added

worker.childopts: "-Xmx1048m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1%ID%"

i disabled the firewall on the server, but when i connect using visualVm, i get an error saying "cannot connet to server using service:jmx:rmi..."

How to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

worker.childopts: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1%ID% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1%ID%

Adding this and opening the ports worked.